# Calculation in select statement is slow in mysql query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have calculations in Mysql select statement. I found it make the query slow.

```
SELECT MIN(a) AS MIN,
       ROUND(100*(a/b), 1) AS mos
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE a > 0
  AND b > 0
  AND c <= 148
  AND d >=-100 HAVING mos <= 300.1
```

If I remove calculations, it is much faster.

```
SELECT a,b
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE a > 0
  AND b > 0
  AND c <= 148
  AND d >=-100
```

I already created a index for a,b,c,d. Any suggestions how to make it faster?

Comment: Are you sure that the total time of the query is faster in the second case, or are you just seeing the first result faster? The aggregate over the whole table in the first query would prevent the first row from being returned until the MIN() has been calculated over _all_ rows.

Comment: Also, why the `HAVING`? Your first query selects the minimum of `a` across all rows (`MIN` is an aggregate function), plus `a% of b` for *the first row it queries* (`ROUND` is *not* an aggregate function).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I tried to run the two queries several time. The first one will take around 0.15 seconds. The second one will take 0.05 seconds.

Comment: @EdGibbs, I tried to remove the `HAVING` and `ROUND(100*(a/b), 1) AS mos` part. The speed is the same.

Comment: First decide what you want to actually calculate and describe it, in words or with an example of a few rows and the wanted output. Then we can find a query that returns the wanted results. Only then, deal with efficiency.

Comment: I was more wondering what it did, not its impact on the speed. Really I'm surprised that individual rows return more quickly than a `MIN` across the rows. Also - be careful about indexing too many columns (such as a, b, c and d). The update/insert/delete time takes a hit for every index you add.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the `mos` calculation that turns out to be the source of your speed problem, you may want to consider adding that as an extra column that you precalculate on insert and update rather than having to recalculate it for every row, every time you run this query.

You could either do this manually in the code that is updating the database, or if you are using a version of mysql that supports triggers, I think you should be able to create a trigger to update the column automatically.

For example, an INSERT trigger might look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_mos BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE_NAME
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.mos = ROUND(100*(NEW.a/NEW.b), 1);
```